# Store.findAll on Model using Fixture Adapter with Ember Data 2.0

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Currently we are upgrading our project to work with Ember 2.0 and Ember Data 2.0.

I have model which is based on fixture adapter. But when i do **store.findAll(modelName)** on the model, i get the following error "TypeError: serializer.normalizeResponse is not a function
   at ember$data$lib$system$store$serializer$response$$normalizeResponseHelper "

**Model**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import FixtureData from '<from somewhere>';
var Model = DS.Model.extend({
    code: DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('string')
});
Model.reopenClass({
    FIXTURES: FixtureData
});
export default Model;
```

**Adapter**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({
    queryFixtures: function (records, query) {
        return records.filter(function (record) {
            for (var key in query) {
                if (query.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    if (record[key] !== query[key]) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        });
    }
});
```

Error Stack

> TypeError: serializer.normalizeResponse is not a function
>       at ember$data$lib$system$store$serializer$response$$normalizeResponseHelper
>   (http://localhost:4201/assets/vendor.js:66323:43)
>       at http://localhost:4201/assets/vendor.js:66627:25
>       at Object.Backburner.run (http://localhost:4201/assets/vendor.js:9692:25)
>       at ember$data$lib$system$store$$Service.extend._adapterRun (http://localhost:4201/assets/vendor.js:71877:33)
>       at http://localhost:4201/assets/vendor.js:66626:15
>       at tryCatch (http://localhost:4201/assets/vendor.js:59683:14)
>       at invokeCallback (http://localhost:4201/assets/vendor.js:59698:15)
>       at publish (http://localhost:4201/assets/vendor.js:59666:9)
>       at http://localhost:4201/assets/vendor.js:39006:7
>       at Queue.invokeWithOnError (http://localhost:4201/assets/vendor.js:10395:18)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FixtureAdapter` has been deprecated in Ember Data 1.0b19 which was released June 5 2015. This is noted in few places and tutorials have yet to catch up:

Sources:

- [Ember Data removal of FixtureAdapter - many of the examples tutorials will break](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/ember-data-removal-of-fixture-adapter-many-of-the-examples-tutorials-will-break/8224)
- [GitHub - Breaking Changes](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes)
- [Ember Data 1.0.0b19 Changelog](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/05/ember-data-1-0-beta-19-released.html#toc_fixture-adapter-removed)

As an alternative to `FixtureAdapter` you can use [Ember Mirage](https://github.com/samselikoff/ember-cli-mirage) which fills the same role while also providing few other features.

Answer (score 0):

Also on the `ember-data-fixture-adapter` github page, they recommend to use PretenderJS now. https://github.com/pretenderjs/pretender